# Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.

Tags: php, wordpress

I have uploaded file of wordpress and when i acces my domain giving this error...
Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.

http://www.ikirsha.com

Answer (score 1):

Few suggestions-

1. Have you changed the siteurl and home options (option_name column) in [wp-prefix]_options table from http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com ??
2. check your htaccess file..is it properly configured
3. Listdeactivate plugins first while uploading and check whether it  is because of any plugin
4. Have you disabled or blocked cookies required by this site? check browser settings

Check these points and let me know

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before. Try resetting your permalinks.
Rewrite your .htaccess codes to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

It should set it to default permalinks.